# Cascaded Angular Material Design sample (with reactive forms)

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

Any good demo/sample showing how to cascade multiple angular mat-autocomplete controls? All the references I've seen only show one standalone autocomplete. I need to link two controls (possibly three) using reactive forms.

A good similar sample could be like an autocomplete for countries, states/provinces and then cities (depending the selection the child controls may or not appears depending if there is information).

The data is pre-loaded in memory (not huge) so there is no need to lookup a sever asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `mat-autocomplete` is applied on ordinary `FormControl`; either independent `FormControl` or that included in `FormGroup`.

For instance; lets suppose that we have **Country** and **Cities**; each of them is `mat-autocomplete`, but you cannot select *city* until you select *country*; right?

I hope that's what you meant.

So; to handle this:

- Make Country formControl as an ordinary mat-autocomplete with no extra configurations.
- Make City formControl as disabled until user select country.
- Add `optionSelected` for `countryAutocomplete` to enable and filter cities.

I made a simple example to explain this example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-autocomplete

if you have 3 or 4; make them like city.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could update this example to the latest Angular. Thanks!